# Server side sorting for calculated fields with pagination?

Tags: java, sql, rest, sorting, pagination

We have to display some tabular data which supports pagination and server-side sorting.
It's a React, JAVA, SQL stack.
While designing the REST API we agreed to return a composite object representing each row of the
table. This object is created as a result of a complex SQL with a lot of business logic.
The object comprises multiple objects, each comprising numerous fields. The idea behind this is to
return a generic object so that we don't have to create request specific DTOs.

However, we just have to use a few fields from this object. A few columns displayed on the UI 
are calculated based on multiple fields in this object. 
The real challenge is when we have to sort these calculated fields on the server-side because we just fetch records that have to be displayed on the page.
We are tempted to refactor the response to match the UI columns by doing calculations on the server-side by we will run into multiple DTO problems.
How can this be achieved in the best possible way? Are there any best practices for this? I couldn't find much on the internet.

Comment: The normal resolution would be to include the sort fields as query parameters which the server can then pass through to the SQL queries (with a limit/offset) to handle the paging as required.

Comment: That was my initial thought. However, the calculations are not straight forward. If we calculate the field on the front end, in order to sort it on server-side, the same calculation will have to be duplicated on the server-side (SQL.) on the same fields

Comment: A good approach for what you need, it would be to use GraphQL instead of DTO. https://graphql.org/learn/queries/. Here is another example: https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/. With this approach, you can sort those calculated fields on the server-side without having multiple DTOs.

Answer (score 0):

For similar problems where the server needs to do a fair amount of processing, rather than returning the answer straight away, I have split the request into several parts.

1) POST a request to the server, to build the results. Rather than return the results to the client,  it stores the results in a results table, in the database, with together with a results reference ID, which is returned to the client as reply to the POST request.
These results will include the calculated fields to sort on. The server may continue to build these results in the background, after returning the reference ID to the client. The server should reply with an 202 Accepted response, rather than 201 Created.

2) GET a request to the server to query this results table, passing the reference ID. including the fields to sort on.  If the server is still building the list, it can return a OK 200, but with a JSON struture depicting 'building'  During this time, the client could be showing a timer animation, and will repeat the request every few seconds.

3) When the table is finally built, the server passes back the paginated data as required.

4) Once finished with, the client can send a DELETE, with the reference ID, to clean up the results table.   However, there should be some kind of cleanup process that will clean up results that are, say older than a day.

See here for more information: https://farazdagi.com/2014/rest-and-long-running-jobs/

also here:
http://restcookbook.com/Resources/asynchroneous-operations/

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to serialize the response to JSON?

If you are using Jackson, I would recommend using JSON Views to avoid having multiple DTOs. It allows you to specify which fields you want to serialize in which circumstances (so dictated by the controller most of the time) and is pretty straightforward to use.

Here's a tutorial on how to use it: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

And an example of how I use it (with an attachment class for example):

This is the model where I define which attribute will be included in which view:

```
public class Attachment {

    @JsonView({
        Attachment.Views.Show.class, Attachment.Views.List.class
    })
    private Long id;

    @JsonView({
        Attachment.Views.Show.class, Attachment.Views.List.class
    })
    private String originalFilename;

    @JsonView({
        Attachment.Views.Show.class
    })
    private String filepath;

    @JsonView({
        Attachment.Views.Show.class
    })
    private String description;

        public static class Views {
        public static class Show {}
        public static class List {}
        public static class Create {}
        public static class Fill {}
        public static class Edit {}
    }

}
```

And here's my controller:

```
public class AttachmentControllerImpl implements AttachmentController {

    @Inject
    private AttachmentService service;

    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public Response show(Long id) {
        Attachment attachment = service.getById(id);

        String json = mapper.writerWithView(Attachment.Views.Show.class).writeObjectAsString(attachment);
    }

    @Override
    public Response list() {
        List<Attachment> attachments = service.getAll();

        String json = mapper.writerWithView(Attachment.Views.List.class).writeObjectAsString(attachments);
    }

}
```

There's really not much more than that to it, very easy to use.